# Receiving channelIdle more than expected (Netty Socket Server)

Tags: java, sockets, jboss, netty

I am facing a problem at my multiplayer java server where I am receiving more than expected channelIdle events. It started 2 days ago where I didn't change the source code and server configuration. What can be the cause for this? Between specific intervals, many people are dropping out of server instantly from idle event. I am using netty.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: can you show me your code ?

Comment: Actually there is no need to paste code since it is a simple override of IdleStateAwareChannelUpstreamHandler. I am logging idle connections at that function. 3-4 days ago, I wasn't getting these. What could be the cause?

Comment: can you tell me what version of netty you use ?

Comment: What netty version does camel 2.6.0 use?

Comment: I am not sure of the version right now but in pom it says 2.6.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that problem was occurring due ISP errors. 
Thanks.